# when i enter wrong password is printing the next line so, how to stop user to access next line if password is incorrect

Tags: python

```
input = input("Enter your code\n ") 

if input == "MB69": 
    
    print ('Mayank bansal') 
    
else:
    print ("code " + input + " is not correct")

print ("welcome")
```

Comment: can't understand your question.

Comment: I could not understand the question, but name the variable somethiing else, input is already a function

Comment: Read the title @Saravanan, the title says that OP wants to prevent printing the next line if the code is incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sys.exit()`. In your code:

```
import sys
inp = input("Enter your code\n ")
if inp == "MB69":
    print('Mayank bansal') 
else: 
    print ("code " + inp + " is not correct")
    sys.exit(0)
print("welcome")
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit

Comment: Thank you very very much 

Comment: If I *completely* answered your question then accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sys.exit(0)`. Or, you can define a function.

```
import sys
input = input("Enter your code\n ") 
if input == "MB69": 
    print ('Mayank bansal') 
else:
    print ("code " + input + " is not correct")
    sys.exit(0)
print ("welcome")
```

By defining a function

```
def success():
    print ("welcome")
input = input("Enter your code\n ") 
if input == "MB69":    
    print ('Mayank bansal') 
    success()
else:
    print ("code " + input + " is not correct")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
def ask():

    password = input("Enter your code\n ") 

    if password == "MB69": 
        
        print ('Mayank bansal') 
        
    else:
        print ("code " + input + " is not correct")
        return
    
    print ("welcome")
```

You could make it more simple -

```
def ask():

        password = input("Enter your code\n ") 

        if password != "MB69": 
            print ("code " + input + " is not correct")
            return
        print ('Mayank bansal')
        print ("welcome")
```

If you do 2nd method, the function will return and stop from running further unless you give the correct password